# Задержка изменения формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два поля ввода, в одно пользователь вводит данные, второе меняется в зависимости от того что пользователь ввел. Как установить задержку 1 сек после которой начнет изменятся второй input?

Comment: через `setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(param); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
~function () {
  var t;

  $('#text-src').on('input', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);

    t = setTimeout(function(input) {
      $('#text-dest').val($(input).val());
    }, 1000, this); 
  })
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text-src" type="text">
&gt;&gt;&gt;
<input id="text-dest" type="text">
```

Comment: вот, то что нужно! А как сделать что бы в обратном направлении таже самая фича работала?

Comment: @user193361 - аналогично. Повесить обработчик с другим таймаутом на второе поле.

Comment: как бы это в одной функции запилить? хотел было мультиселектором вешать функцию, но как изменить селектор в setTimeout не догоню

Comment: @user193361, зачем это делать в одной функции? Вынеси логику в jQuery-плагин и дважды его примени. Другой вариан - повесить data-атрибуты с другим инпутом на инпуты.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю нужно что то такое.

Для этого есть функция [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce), можно найти в библиотеках Underscore/Lodash.
Она выполнятся только через секунду после последнего ее вызова.

```js
var $first = document.getElementById( 'first' );
var $second = document.getElementById( 'second' );

var debouncedFunction = _.debounce( function() {
  $second
    .placeholder = $first.value;
}, 1000 );

$first.addEventListener( 'input', debouncedFunction );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>


<label>Первое поле
  <input id='first' />
</label>

<br />

<label>Второе поле
  <input id='second' placeholder='' />
</label>
```

Comment: не хочу использовать дополнительную библиотеку только из-за одной функции, думаю что это можно оформить на сухом jquery, а вообще результат тот который мне нужен

Comment: Плагин для jquery https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce
Или скопировать с исходников  http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-83

Answer (score 1):

Пробуем так вот:

```js
$('#enter-text').on('change', function(){
 var our_text = $(this).val();
 setTimeout (function() {
  $('#text').val(our_text)
 }, 1000); 
})
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 30px auto;
 text-align: center;
}
input {
 border: 2px solid #747474;
 padding: 15px 30px;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <input id='enter-text' type="text" />
 <p>You entered:</p>
 <input id="text"> 
</div>
```

Comment: не то, у вас получается второй инпут "тормозит" на одну секунду, а мне нужно что бы значение во второй форме менялось через одну секунду после того как пользователь закончил ввод

Comment: Иногда так хочется поставить комментарию минус... @user193361, а в чём разница? UPDATE: Всё-таки понял. Надо как-то понятнее формулировать что ли.

Comment: Тогда пробуем поменять keyup на change.

Comment: и все равно ваш второй инпут изменяет свое содержание только после того как первый потеряет фокус